# How can you auto-calibrate a conductance sensor?

Tags: signal-processing, signal-integrity, calibration, signal-theory

Sensors need to be calibrated every so often, so that the voltage/current change due to the change in the conductance is always the same, and the signal conditioning of that voltage/current is always gives the same output for the same input. i.e, it needs to be calibrated to remove gain and offset error that occur over time.

What are the basic principles for auto-calibration? I've looked on-line and on Google scholar but cannot find anything that explains anything clearly.

I am only looking for the basic principles to get me started.

Comment: It's highly situational, and typically only removes certain errors. For example, you might ground the input of an ADC through a switch, measure the reading (more likely take many measurements and average them) and then subtract that reading off subsequent readings, but the voltage you measure for the zero will be slightly corrupted by noise, the effect of bias current may be slightly different because of different source resistances etc.

Comment: This would be application specific, so you should provide more information about your sensor and any additional circuitry.

Comment: For the sensor it really depends on the sensor. Sometimes you can subject it to a well-controlled current/voltage, etc., measure the response, compare it with expected behavior, and then do an according transformation on subsequent measurements.

Comment: @HKOB surely that will only help calibrate the signal conditioning part of the circuit, and not the actual sensor. Am I right?

Comment: @Blue7 Some sensors 'age' from various processes, e.g. oxidation, diffusion, radiation, etc. Typically problems like that are worse in high temperature/current conditions. If you know something about how that aging process works you could try to measure the development and use it to calibrate results.

Comment: In general wouldn't you use the signal conditioning circuit to offset any inherent offset or scale error to generate the desired signal output for a given input? HKOB, Naz and Sphero are spot on. +1 each.

Comment: @HKOB Thank you, that is very helpful. I will look into how conductance sensors "age". Regarding your first comment " well-controlled current/voltage, etc., measure the response, compare it with expected behaviour", is this for the signal conditioning calibration. Am I even correct in thinking that there are two parts to the calibration process, calibrating 1) the sensor, and 2) the signal conditioning?

Comment: @Blue7  What sort of material are you going to measure?  Are you going to measure bulk conductance or surface conductance?

Comment: @SeanBoddy I think the problem is that the inherent offset changes over time, so the signal conditioning needs to be readjusted periodicaly.

Comment: I don't do much auto calibration, but for a conductance measurement you'd have to have some sort of "standard" (calibrated) resistor on board.  You might check the standard on start up (or sometime.) Or use the standard in a difference  (bridge type) measurement.  What sort of conductance range?  (Things get harder at low or high values.)

Comment: @NickAlexeev bulk conductivity of water based on streaming potential. I've left this out of the question because it is quite complicated and may not even be the final way I approach this problem. I didn't want to distract from the main focus on the basics of auto calibration.

Comment: @Blue7 Yes, I think you are correct in that subdivision, although you can probably do both in one sweep in many cases. Whether you actually want to do both separately or both at once probably depends on how well the easiest method you can think of works, and how tough your requirements are. Regarding the "well controlled (etc.)" I meant to operate the sensor with a known bias, or perhaps even in a different operating mode (could be solved by switching).

Comment: If the problem isn't aging, adding data for air pressure (weather) and ambient temperature may also help in calibration.

Answer (score 2):

The instruments that measure bulk conductivity<sup>1</sup> are calibrated with standard solution.  As solution with known conductivity is introduced and the cell constant is measured.  The conductivity cell and the circuitry are calibrated at the same time.

Such calibration would be done daily or weekly.  I wouldn't call it fully automatic calibration, though, because the standard solution is introduced by an operator.

As Hkob had mentioned in his [comment](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/155695/how-can-you-auto-calibrate-a-conductance-sensor#comment315275_155695), contamination and chemical reactions can gradually change the cell constant of the conductivity cell.  Those are faster and more pronounced that the drifts in the analog front end.  The calibration with standard solution takes care of both.

**Additional reading**
[Conductivity Theory and Practice](http://www.tau.ac.il/~chemlaba/Files/Theoryconductivity.pdf) (PDF, p.20 deal with determination of the cell constant)

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Conductivity of water is one of the indicators of quality, for example.</sub>

Comment: This. Since you are using fluid conductivity cells, there's no way to actually calibrate it without using a standard, and it's probably impractical to engineer the system to automatically insert the standard solution. Anything put into the circuitry could only reliably verify that the output side is working. So, you could calibrate the meter movement/readout automatically, assuming that the sensor is always calibrated to have the same output characteristic.

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR - This won't work for your conductivity cell, but contains some basic considerations.**

As far as basic principles go, all calibration has to compare a given output with a known input and then make adjustments to have the output correctly follow the input. This may or may not involve taking measurements of different known quantities depending on how linear the phenomenon being used is.

Any signal being measured electronically will have to based on current or voltage. It is entirely possible to install a calibration grade fixed current or voltage source into any piece of electronics, even if it can get pretty expensive. This would have to serve as the known quantity. As noted in Nick's answer though, it can't really help you with calibration of a conductivity cell. Even passing a known current through the cell won't be able to tell you how it actually responds to varying conductivity, because the conductivity of the fluid and the resistivity of the cell would still be unknown (and changing).

The output side of almost any measurement circuitry could be verified against these built in known quantities, and if you have more than one known input, both offset and scale can be checked. To check linearity, you'd need many known values, and cost increases as you build in more accuracy. To be fair, there are some really great relatively cheap reference supplies that would probably be very close, as long as you don't need .00001% accuracy.

Once the known quantity is routed to the input, it's simply a matter of sequencing a series of adjustments through the hardware. I say simply, but the processors or microcontrollers doing this can be pretty cool, doing a little math, feeding numbers into a DAC or possibly outputting a new voltage to an amplifier. To automate the process, some central task master would have to be able to control most of the offsets, multipliers and such. And depending on what the needs of the system are, a lot of this can be internalized by the controller itself, requiring less analog conditioning than might have been required before microcontrollers got pretty cheap.